# Get list of all azure policy assignment using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

I'm trying to get the list of all policy assignments created in azure using the below commands.

However when I scope the assignment to the resource group, below command does not return that assignment in its output. Please advise on this further.

**Powershell commands:**

To get all policy assignment:

```
Get-AzPolicyAssignment
```

This commands return list of assignments scoped to only subscriptions & management groups

To get specific policy assignment which is scoped to resource group:

```
$ResourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name 'ResourceGroup01'
Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'PolicyAssignment01' -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
```

This commands does not return any policy assignment

**Reference links:**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermpolicyassignment?view=azurermps-6.13.0
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-5.4.0

Comment: COuld you  please check if you have assigned the policy to the group?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you assign policy?

Answer (score 0):

The command looks correct.

```
PS C:\> $ResourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name '<RESOURCE GROUP>'
PS C:\> Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Name '<Policy Name>' -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
```

Two things to check :

1. $ResourceGroup

You could check whether there is value stored in the object.

2. You could run `Get-AzPolicyAssignment -scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceId`

You could see  all policies assigned for the resource group. And cross check whether you have the required policy name from the output.