# Get Azure Policy names

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Having read the question on the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812182/get-list-of-all-azure-policy-assignment-using-powershell) , I would like to get a list of all the names of Azure policies assigned to the tenant irrespective of the scope (subscription, management group etc).

I ran the snippet `Get-AzPolicyAssignment | select Name` I had some names, but majority of the names that came back look like GUIDs. What is the correct code to work out the actual policy name as displayed on the portal and the scope of the policy?

I would get output like the below:

```
ISO Policy xxx
437878sfdf787483eaed87423
```

However when looking in the portal, they all have proper descriptive names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below cmdlet to pull the list and display name's of the policy assignments that are showing in the portal.

`Get-AzPolicyAssignment | Select-Object -ExpandProperty properties | Select-Object -Property DisplayName,Scope | Format-Table`

Refer to this sample output screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I ran the snippet `Get-AzPolicyAssignment | select Name` I had some names, but majority of the names that came back look like GUIDs. What is the correct code to work out the actual policy name as displayed on the portal and the scope of the policy?

Alternatively, you can use `Azure CLI` commands to check the **name** and **scope** of a policy assignment.

```kotlin
 az policy assignment list --query '[].{AssignmentName: displayName, Scope: scope}' --output table
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [az policy assignment list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/policy/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-policy-assignment-list)